# How to change a delimiter from pipe to tab format

Tags: postgresql, tabs, copy, pipe

I have a file with RRF which have pipe as delimiter . I need to change into tab format to load data into table in postgres . I used the folowing commands . It throw unquoted new line found in data error

```
sed 's/\|/  /g' < demo_text.RRF > demo_text.TAB

\copy demo_table from 'path of the file \demo_text.TAB' DELIMITER E'\t' CSV HEADER;
```

How to import data into table

Comment: Are we supposed to know what RRF is?  Why not just set the delimiter in the COPY command to be what you want it to be?

Comment: Also why `tab` the default for the CSV format is a `,`. `tab` is the default for the text format.

Comment: Hi , RRF stands for Rich Release Format . I set pipe as delimiter but it throws character exceeds as it’s data type limit as it consider whole value as first column